# How can I return a dictionary of multiple features, from a tf.data.Dataset, created from generator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I have an example dataset like below:

```
feature_1    feature_2    label
4            5            1
4            3            1
4            6            2
...
```

I have created a `tf.feature_column.embedding_column` for each feature (feature_1 and feature_2), so I have to return from my `train_input_fn` a dictionary of features, where the keys have the same name with the features. My input function is given below:

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, output_types, output_shapes, batch_size, feature_names):
    """
    Provides the data pipeline for the training process.
    :param features: (numpy.array) A numpy array that holds the training features.
    :param labels: (numpy.array) A numpy array that holds the target variable.
    :param output_types: (tuple(tensorflow.DType)) A tuple containing the data type of each component yielded.
    :param output_shapes: (tuple(tensorflow.TensorShape)) A tuple containing the shape of each component yielded.
    :param batch_size: (int) The size of every batch.
    :return: (dict, int) A dictionary of key -> value for every feature and the target label.
    """
    def gen():
        for f, l in zip(features, labels):
            yield f, l

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types, output_shapes)
    # If we do repeat without any argument we actually create and infinite loop.
    # That is preferred, we can now control the iterations via epochs.
    ds = ds.repeat().batch(batch_size)
    feature, label = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return {'feature': feature}, label
```

How can I return something like:

`{'feature_1': x_1, 'feature_2': x_2}`

Comment: Is `features` an array containing both `feature_1` and `feature_2`, e.g. with shape 2xN or Nx2?

Comment: Yes it's a Nx2 array.

Answer (score 0):

This small couple of changes should do it:

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, output_types, output_shapes, batch_size, feature_names):
    """
    Provides the data pipeline for the training process.
    :param features: (numpy.array) A numpy array that holds the training features.
    :param labels: (numpy.array) A numpy array that holds the target variable.
    :param output_types: (tuple(tensorflow.DType)) A tuple containing the data type of each component yielded.
    :param output_shapes: (tuple(tensorflow.TensorShape)) A tuple containing the shape of each component yielded.
    :param batch_size: (int) The size of every batch.
    :return: (dict, int) A dictionary of key -> value for every feature and the target label.
    """
    def gen():
        for f, l in zip(features, labels):
            yield f, l

    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_types, output_shapes)
    # If we do repeat without any argument we actually create and infinite loop.
    # That is preferred, we can now control the iterations via epochs.
    ds = ds.repeat().batch(batch_size)
    feature, label = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return {'feature_1': feature[:, 0], 'feature_2': feature[:, 1]}, label
```